# In Unity how do i make the camera follow a character in the y axis..?

Tags: unity, camera

I have a character which keeps moving in the y-axis and the camera needs to be fixed to follow with the character for some extent and when the character falls down camera should freeze at the point. The attached image will make u understand better.

[image]

Comment: "*freeze at the point*"? What point? What part of the image do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

Put a script on the camera, get a reference to the 'player' gameobject, then move the camera vertically to match the player when the player is higher than the camera:

```
void Update() {
  if (player.transform.position.y > this.transform.position.y) {  
    this.transform.position.y = player.transform.position.y;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can't update the transform like that I think, you'd have to create a new Vector3 or use a temporary variable.

Comment: I think you're right; I'm pretty sure I wasn't in Unity when I wrote that, so consider it pseudo-code.